# How does $\frac{1}{2}(n-s+1)(n-s)$ equal $\binom{n-s+1}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness

Maybe a basic question, but I'm strolling through graph theory at the moment after a few years out of tertiary mathematics. There is a theorem that if a graph $G$ has $s$ connected components, then
$$
n - s \le k \le \frac{n-s+1}{2},
$$
where $n$ is the number of vertices and $k$ is the number of edges.

During the proof, the final two lines state: $$ \frac{1}{2}(n-s+1)(n-s) = \binom{n-s+1}{2}$$

It doesn't really go into explaining how that is the case and I found it hard to phrase into the search engine what it is that I am looking for, but I'm basically looking for a general explanation as to why that is.

Comment: What is your definition of binomial coefficient? Just apply it.

Comment: $\binom k2=\frac {k!}{2!\, (k-2)!}=\frac {k(k-1)}2$

Comment: I knew this would make me feel silly. Thanks though guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy to prove using the factorial definition of combination:

$${n-s+1 \choose 2}=\frac{(n-s+1)!}{(n-s-1)!\cdot 2!}=\frac{(n-s+1)(n-s)}{2}$$